# How to request for a json file from javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, json, httprequest

i have a url which returns a json file(i have typed the url in the address bar and it showed the json output) but i don't know how to request for the json file in javascript. can anybody help me?
here's the code:

```
var url = 'http://www.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=kalutara&format=json&num_of_days=4&key=myKey' ;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
      http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  http_request.open('GET', url, true); 
  http_request.send(null);
   http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ( http_request.readyState == 4) {
      if ( http_request.status == 200)
        success( http_request.responseText);alert(http_request.responseText);
      else if (failure)
        failure( http_request.status,  http_request.statusText);
    }
  };
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you json file looks like.
For e.g.
If the file contains something like

```
var obj = 
{
 //Object definition...
}
```

Then you can just use the regular script tag to be able to use the json object.
If the file in format:

```
{
 //Object Definiton
}
```

then you can read the contents as defined in your post (Using XMLHTTP request) however then use eval function to make it available in the page something like the one below in your success() method:

```
eval("var obj = " + http_request.responseText);
```